# Solr IP Address Field Type

Tags: java, solr, lucene, ip

Is there a special field type in Solr for IP addresses that would allow you to search within a range of IP addresses?  The only thing I can think of is to use Guava's InetAddresses.coerceToInteger and InetAddresses.fromInteger to store the IP in integer format.  Then I would have to do the conversion every time I create a document or search within an IP range.  I was hoping there was a field type that took care of all this.

Comment: I think you can use the [Path Hierarchy Tokenizer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-PathHierarchyTokenizer) for this defining the dot as delimiter. I'll play around with it.

Comment: How do you want to search for IP-ranges and what do you want as result? Something like `ip:192.168` and then get everything that starts with it?

Comment: This is quite an old topic. Was there anything added to Solr in the meantime? I have a similar use case. My data is in a PostsgreSQL database and I want to improve search speed. But I also need the functionality to search for network including IP addresses, get and let to work with IP ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is no such field [included by default](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Field+Types+Included+with+Solr) but it shouldn't be too hard to write your own by extending the FieldType class and using Guava InetAddresses and Guava converter.  Once you have your custom class defined, [see here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#FieldType) for how to implement the field in the schema.xml

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to do the conversion manually in case we have something else accessing the index in the future.  We'd have to make sure it implements the same converter.  If someone searched the index directly then they'd also have to do the conversion manually.

I wasn't aware of Converter so if I do have to do the conversion manually this will be a nice addition.

Comment: Were you suggesting that I extend org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType in Solr and use Converter inside of my custom type?  I think this is probably the only possibly solution to have Solr do the conversion automatically.

Comment: Yep, I don't think you can get away without having custom type. It should be fairly simple though as the converted data is of integer type which suggests you should be first looking at using `TrieIntField` as the extension base, unless you care about ipv6 addresses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory` to get a basic IP search working. With a fielType like this

```xml
<fieldType name="ip_address" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory" delimiter="." replace="."/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

You can perform searches like `q=ip:192.168` that would return all IPs start with `192.168.*.*`

The example `192.168.1.2` would get tokenized as

- 192
- 192.168
- 192.168.1
- 192.168.1.2

Comment: This could probably be helpful to others but I don't think this is quite the way I need to search IP ranges.